# How to have a button focused when pressing 'Tab' button in javaFX?

Tags: css, javafx, hover, focus, javafx-8

[This is the Image link of my fxml file...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGrAx.png)

In the above shown window of a simple form in javaFx when I press tab button it will go to ok button and next tab will shift to cancel button. However the focus as shown on the textfield is not transferred to the buttons.
But when the mouse cursor is moved on them the hover effect works perfectly.
How to make these buttons focused/hovered with different colors when pressing the tab button (not by moving the mouse cursor on them)?
Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the colors for the buttons in a stylesheeet.

```
public class YourApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        TextField txt = new TextField("test");

        Button btnOk = new Button("OK");
        btnOk.setId("buttonOk");

        Button btnCancel = new Button("Cancel");
        btnCancel.setId("buttonCancel");

        VBox box = new VBox(txt, btnOk, btnCancel);
        Scene scene = new Scene(box);

        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("yourApp.css").toExternalForm());

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

yourApp.css:

```
#buttonCancel:hover,
#buttonCancel:focused {
    -fx-background-color: blue;
}
#buttonOk:hover,
#buttonOk:focused{
    -fx-background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That was too easy like css in html ;)